# firestore query for user uploads

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Hi Everyone I have users being able to upload images and the firestore document associated with the firebase storage, the firestore document has the user that uploaded its firebase uid.

I am trying to query for all images that have that uid in the collection.
As you can see I am trying to use the current users uid that is stored in state.

```
created() {
    var assetsRef = db.collection('Assets')
    var query = assetsRef.where('user', '==', this.$store.state.user)
    console.log(query)
}
```

A Doc from firestore looks  like this:

```
    authors
(array)
0
"bakerMan"
description
"Delicous chocolate chip cookies"
imageurl
0
"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/hydra-games.appspot.com/o/whitney-wright-282066-unsplash.jpg?alt=media&token=fba56452-4eee-4e02-9cfa-f993723f2bdd"
slug
"the-best-cookies-ever"
title
"The Best cookies ever"
user
"qwrNDu4ViAOl1y6RCGZ6F9xHywX2"
```

I am trying to get that user id above to be able to allow me to return  the whole document.

It returns:

```
Query$$1 {_query: Query, firestore: Firestore}
firestore: Firestore {_dataConverter: UserDataConverter, …}
_query: Query {path: ResourcePath, explicitOrderBy: Array(0), filters: Array(1), limit: null, startAt: null, …}
__proto__: Object
```

I cannot seem to find my doc information within the object.

thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code builds a query, but is not executing that query yet. To execute the query, you need to either call `get()` (to get the results once) or `onSnapshot()` (to start monitoring) on the query. So for example:

```
query.get().then((querySnapshot) => {
  querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
    console.log(doc.data());
  });
})
```

Note that this is covered quite well in the Firebase documentation, so I highly recommend spending some time there. For example, in the documentation on [getting documents from a collection](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_multiple_documents_from_a_collection).

Comment: Thanks you very much!